# How do I separate data models and local-data models in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I hope I can expain myself what I mean.

Let's say I have a `car` resource. The car has the attributes `color`, `name` or whatever.

I get the list of cars using a service, something like `cars.index()`.

But in the interface I have all the cars and when I click on one car, a little popup appears showing the inputs to edit the `color` and the `name`.

And here comes the issue. Where do I save the `displayingInputs` attribute?

1. Should I save it directly in the car resource and then just send the original attributes when submitting to the updated resource?
2. Should I create a new service called `carWidget` or something along the lines that each one has something like:

   ```
   {
     car: cars.get(carId),
     displayingInputs: false
   }
   ```
3. Should I store the `displayingInputs` inside a `carWidget` directive scope? What happens if I need to change the `displayingInputs from the parent scope? (for example when making a "display all"/"hide all" button)
4. Something else?

My best bet is #3, but I'm not sure how should I access the `displayingInputs` from outside the widget.

Comment: a very useful example: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy

Comment: What's the purpose of `displayingInputs`?

Comment: displayingInputs would be a boolean value indicating whether the inputs are being displayed for that car or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your `car` model clean, you can have a separate variable `editedCar` and display each popup with `ng-show="car == editedCar"`.

If multiple cars can be edited at the same time, `editedCars` can be an associative array (car ID => boolean) and display popups using `ng-show="editedCars[car.id]"`.

Another way not to send certain car properties is to prefix their name with a `$` sign. This was simply use `car.$displayingInputs`. Be careful for name collisions as Angular uses this prefix to store internal data.

From the [angular.toJson doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.toJson):

> Serializes input into a JSON-formatted string. Properties with leading
>   $ characters will be stripped since angular uses this notation
>   internally.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about prefixing properties with $. But is ok to use? I mean, does the documentation endorses using that method when doing this kind of things?

Comment: I didn't find that said explicitly. Stripping properties starting with $ is documented. The only thing that is not future proof is that your property name may collide with a next version of Angular. If you call your property like `$myCompanyNameDisplayingInputs` you're pretty safe.